# Subscribing to onChange jQuery dart

Tags: jquery, dart

I am trying to listen to the jQuery `onchange` event in dart as the native onchange event is not firing when using a jQuery date picker.

Here is my current code

```
js.context.jQuery("#venueDatePicker").on("change", new js.Callback.many((e, data) {
    print("Will be executed");
}));
```

Here is the error i am getting

```
malformed type: line 61 pos 63: type 'js.Callback' is not loaded
            js.context.jQuery("#venueDatePicker").on("change", new js.Callback.many((e, data) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not tested but I think it should be like:

```dart
js.context.callMethod(r'$', ["#venueDatePicker"])
    .callMethod('on', ["change", (e, data) {
      print("Will be executed");
    }]);
```

Comment: `js.Callback` was removed. You can directly use Dart Functions.

Comment: NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'callMethod'
Receiver: Instance of 'JsObject'
Arguments: ["$", Instance(length:1) of '_GrowableList']

Comment: if your JS code in your question works try `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: i think it means the callMethod method dosent exist for some reason

Comment: Do you have the script tags in your HTML page? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547730

Comment: Yes i have all of the required script tags

Comment: maybe this one https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15065#c11 is related?

Comment: Yes i have added them

Comment: Are you using `dart:js` or [js package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) ? The above code snippet assume you are using `dart:js`.

Comment: my fault was using js package will give it a try with dart:js on monday