# Gmaps LatLng not found in MouseEvent using angular.dart

Tags: google-maps, dart, latitude-longitude, angular-dart, dart-js-interop

Am working in an angular.dart project that uses gmaps.
And i want to get the LatLng value on map click.
My map.html :

```dart
<div id="map" ng-click="ctrl.mapClick($event)"></div>
```

My DartCtrl :

```dart
 void mapClick(e){
    print(e.runtimeType); //MouseEvent
    print(e.latLng); //error : Undifined function mapClick ...
 }
```

Any idea to get LatLng value without writing something like :

```dart
map.onClick.listen((e){
print(e.latLng);
});
```

*This happend in dartium so its not related to dart2js.
and think you ..

Comment: Does this work? `map.onClick.listen((e){
print(e.latLng);
});`

Comment: yeah sure where map is querySelector('#map')

Comment: I can' believe that. The `MouseEvent` has no `latLng` getter, how should that work? Can you check if the `e.detail` provides any useful information?

Comment: `e.detail` prints `1`, its supposed work because it uses Dart style listener

Comment: What is supposed to work? Your second example? As far as I know you get the same 'dart:html' `MouseEvent` object and it does *not* have a `latLng` getter in both cases.

Comment: Well thats always the case with gmaps, i gess that it alter the MouseEvent object because when i ask for the runtimeType in the listner i get something like `MouseEvent (:1)`

Comment: Runtime type isn't very reliable in Dart (just for debugging purposes). But I suppose as well that GMap adds a property to the event object. You need dart-js-interop to access this property because Dart doesn't support dynamically added fields/methods on classes. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Are you using [google_maps package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps) to instantiate the map or are you creating the map directly with `dart:js` ?

Comment: yeah am using [google_maps package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps) to handle the map. after some digging i found that when using listener [google_maps package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps) creates a MouseEvent from the package MouseEvent event that have the `latLng` property. that explain the difference between $event's MouseEvent and listeners 'MouseEvent'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MouseEvent returned is not the native one neither inherit from HTML's MouseEvent, it's 'src/generated/core/events/mouse_event.dart' so there s no possible way that my example work.
A better approach would be to create an NgDecorator that have a callback method that returns the special MouseEvent wish contains the LatLng

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like

```dart
import 'dart:js';
```

...

```dart
new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(e)['latLng']
```

(not tested)

for Dart-js-interop see also [js interop compiled with dart2js error - Uncaught NoSuchMethodError : method not found:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547730/)

Comment: I just tested it 'new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(e)['latLng']' return null

Comment: Sorry, then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: i think that normally gmaps add the latLng to MouseEvent before the listener method is executed, which doesn't happened if ng-click is used instead

Comment: I think gmaps has to add the property before it fires the event. So the property should be available in any case when you receive the event.

Comment: Thinks a lot man ! i really appreciate the time you spent locking for a solution to my problem !

Comment: I will to try to go deeper and if i got any idea of how to bypass the issues i will post it